# Unusual Django Behaviour

Tags: python, django

I am starting out with Django and trying to build a simple SQLLite based App.

```
 Environment 
  Django 1.7
  Python 3.3.2 
  Windows Vista OS 32bit
```

I am facing a frustrating issue loading pages. The pages have a bunch of JS and CSS files , the thing is page loads

sometimes and most of the items the css or js does not seem to have effect even though   server trace shows 200 HTTP

response for them.

This is a screen shot when it works (Opera)

[image: working request]

Now the pic when this does not work (Opera)

[image: Does not work]

The problem is on both occasions the request is returning with 200 status.

I am using static folder inside my projects where all the js and css files are kept

Here is how I am accessing them

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/uploadfile/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/uploadfile/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/uploadfile/js/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/uploadfile/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/uploadfile/js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/uploadfile/css/jquery.fullPage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/uploadfile/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

In Chrome I get a similar behavior but this time the request is shown as pending 
[image: chrome]

I am really confused how to proceed this is really taking a lot of time to test my stuff. I will be extremely obliged if somebody can give me some pointers.

Comment: why `/static/` use `{% static`

Comment: for now I am just trying to eliminate the "variables"

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of browser caching. Browser will show a `200` status code which means `OK` *i.e.* the file was found on the server. But the browser will not bother fetching the file from the server and will load it from cache.

After you modify a static file, you should reload the page by hitting `CTRL-R`. This will force browser to load files from the server instead of the cache.

**Trivia**: When you perform a reload, if the static files are changed, the browser will show a `200` status code. But if the files are unchanged, it will show a `304` status code meaning `NOT MODIFIED`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However the issue is that it is not loading from cache even. The css is not reflecting and the javascript is not working. :(.